# Loop in bash to create symlinks after every git pull

Tags: linux, bash, git, symbolic-link

I have a scenario where I have a git repository that I do a git pull every x minutes, in the following dir: /opt/repo/

In this repository I have some directories like:

- /opt/repo/dir1
- /opt/repo/dir2
- /opt/repo/dir3

that are created on the repo dinamycally and retrieved in every git pull.

What I need to do is, after every git pull, create a symlink for those directories (only the new ones) on another path:

`/var/www/themes/`

Manually, what I do is the following:

```
$ cd /var/www/themes
$ ln -s /opt/repo/dir1 . 
$ ln -s /opt/repo/dir2 . 
$ ln -s /opt/repo/dir3 .
```

Is there a way to do that in every call? I don't want to recreate the existing symlinks, just create for the ones that doesn't exist yet.

====

SYN solution works, I just had to invert -maxdepth and type order (I was running it over Ubuntu 16 it that matters).

Comment: have you looked at commit hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your repository root, you would have a `.git` subdir. In there, you should be able to install a post-update hook:

```
$ cd /opt/repo
$ test -d .git/hooks || mkdir .git/hooks
$ cat <<EOF >.git/hooks/post-update
#!/bin/sh

cd /opt/repo
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read dir
    do
        test "$dir" = .git && continue
        test -e "/var/www/themes/$dir" && continue
        ln -sf "/opt/repo/$dir" /var/www/themes
    done
EOF
$ chmod +x .git/hooks/post-update
```

This assuming the user pulling from git also has permissions to create those links, ...

Comment: Thanks, it seems the right way! But I get this: find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: I've updated my code with the debug. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Aparently if you invert the -maxdepth and type, it works! Thanks again, accepting answer, but if you could "fix" it. Maybe it's related to Ubuntu syntax somehow. Weird, right? :-)

Comment: Weird though, I'm positive setting type then maxdepth works (GNU findutils, debian 8).

Comment: I know Syn, didn't expect that as well (that's why I didn't try to invert its order at first... but well, you know how things work in IT: Murphy's law apply all the time! )